# Magento 1.x Database tables with product data

Tags: product, database, magento-1, table

Which tables are the ones in the database that have all the product data in a Magento 1.x system?

Comment: There are many tables use for save product data in magento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Main table for products in magento:**

**catalog_product_entity**

> Above table is an act as main table, for that child tables are staring
>   with “catalog_product_entity_” prefix.

- catalog_product_entity_datetime – Product – date attribute are stored here. Ex: New From, New To
- catalog_product_entity_decimal – Product price related values.
- catalog_product_entity_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_int – Product Status, Visiblity etc..
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery – product images path, Thumb , small, etc
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value – Product image,product image position,  title info & position of image info, etc
- catalog_product_entity_tier_price – Product tier product
- catalog_product_entity_varchar – Product name, URL, etc

**Bundled product** – information: Will get bundled product associated
values from below table

- catalog_product_bundle_option
- catalog_product_bundle_option_value
- catalog_product_bundle_selection

**Related to downloaded product information.**

- catalog_product_link
- catalog_product_link_attribute
- catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
- catalog_product_link_attribute_int
- catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar
- catalog_product_link_type

**Product custom option** information will get from below tables

- catalog_product_option
- catalog_product_option_price
- catalog_product_option_title
- catalog_product_option_type_price
- catalog_product_option_type_title
- catalog_product_option_type_value

**Configurable product and Grouped product** information will get it from below tables

- catalog_product_super_attribute
- catalog_product_super_attribute_label
- catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing
- catalog_product_super_link

Source: jutesenthil

Comment: Supa Supa Supa!